# Proportionately re-sizing ImageView when width is set to fill parent

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to proportionally set the height of an ImageView if the width is set to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`?

It appears there is no direct way of adjusting an ImageView without skewing one of it's dimensions. This seems bizarre given the application is expected to support a slew of screen sizes and resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wrap_content` for the height and set the correct scale type (either in code or via the `android:scaleType` attribute in XML). You are probably looking for `CENTER_INSIDE`/`android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

See [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: ScaleType works for ImageView but does not exist for custom View's which contain drawables, such as a custom button. Is there a way to scale any type of view in this fashion?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, might be but I never needed this. This works only for ImageViews, but wasn't that the question?

Comment: Yes. This satisfies the question. I figure you may also know how this applies to custom views. I find scaling in Android to be a bit confusing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: For Views, the best way I know is overriding onDraw and forcing the ratio there